# Photoshop - Can't Automate Filter > Pixelate > Crystallization with Script

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I'm working on a simple script for Photoshop that applies Filter > Pixelate > Crystallization with cell size 10 however it seems that Photoshop doesn't include a function like it does for other filters like applyGaussianBlur

Is there a way to use this filter programmatically?

This has a list of the available filters but not a way to use unincluded ones (to my very limited knowledge) https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Photoshop/ArtLayer.html

I don't know if there is a way to use this or not

https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/CEP/event_codes.html?highlight=crystal EventID is
1131574132

Answer (score 0):

Event IDs are used in Action Manager code (JSX) or BatchPlay (newer Photoshops, UXP Framework). Here's the Action Manager snippet. `10` is the Cell Size value for the filter.

```js
var desc = new ActionDescriptor();
desc.putInteger( charIDToTypeID('ClSz'), 10 );
executeAction( charIDToTypeID('Crst'), desc, DialogModes.NO );
```